# Does using spacewalk require RHEL subscription?

Tags: linux, yum, rpm, repository, spacewalk

Planning to use spacewalk for patch management on RHEL Linux servers built in amazon web services. Can someone clarify if it requires a direct subscription from RHEL for downloading packages from their repositories.

The statement from below link made me ask this question.

https://fedorahosted.org/spacewalk/wiki/HowToInstall

```
Red Hat Optional Server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)

When using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 or 7, make sure you are subscribed to the appropriate Red Hat Optional Server channel:

Red Hat Optional Server 6 , OR
Red Hat Optional Server 7
```

Answer (score 0):

No it does not require RHEL subscription. You can use CentOS and EPEL. Only when you use real RHEL you may miss some dependencies. They are located in Optional channel which you must manually enable.